# DunitX and FinalBuilder

Tags: delphi, c++builder, finalbuilder, dunitx

I have both C++ and Delphi tests in DunitX. I am trying to get it to Build in FinalBuilder. C++ tests builds fine, but Delphi tests has the error:

```
"Error creating cfg file: C:\Tests.cfg Error expanding variables in Library Path : [Expression Error]: Variable\Object "DUnitX" does not exist! [$(DUnitX.);$(BDSLIB)\Win32\rele]
```

The FinalBuilder does not have a DunitX action, but has Dunit and NUnit ones. For both C++ and Delphi ones the action is Build. Thoughts on FinalBuilder integration appreciated.

IDE: RAD Berlin 10.1

FinalBuilder: 8

Comment: Are you sure that dot belongs there?

Comment: @StefanGlienke Which dot?

Comment: The one in `$(DUnitX.)` see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the failing project and look into the project options

Delphi Compiler -> Search path for any Target might contain $(DUnitX.) <- notice the dot

Make sure to remove the dot and make sure that you have the DUnitX environment variable set - for additional information see this article: https://www.finalbuilder.com/resources/blogs/postid/702/dunitx-has-a-wizard

If you are using the DUnitX version that ships with Delphi you can just remove the `$(DUnitX.)` from the search path as the DUnitX sources should be in the BDSLib directory.

However keep in mind that when you create new DUnitX projects via the Wizard it adds that variable to the project (that is probably where it came from originally) which then might again fail when building with FinalBuilder. I don't know how it behaves without that wrong dot if the variable does not exist.

Comment: Yea, There was no '.' but when I removed $DunitX from the search, it builds. Thanks for the tip.